# How to update some record table from anothor table with key value in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have table user like this

```
| ID | user | vehicle_ID | vehicle_Desc |
-----------------------------------------
| 1  | Jhon |    201     |      Car     |
| 2  | Cris |    202     |      Car     |
```

I have table vehicle like this

```
| ID  |   Vehicle  |
---------------------
| 201 |    Car     |
| 202 | Motorcycle |
```

how to update vehicle_Desc on Cris record, according to the benchmark in table vehicle? use laravel

Comment: What benchmark are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple SQL query, but it is easier to be executed in raw SQL than through the built-in query builder:

```
$userId = 2; // id of chris

$sql = <<<SQL
    UPDATE u
    SET u.vehicle_desc = v.vehicle
    FROM users u
        INNER JOIN vehicles v ON v.id = u.vehicle_id
    WHERE u.id = ?
SQL;
\DB::statement($sql, [$userId]);
```

Comment: how is it with query builder laravel?

Comment: No idea, never joined with the query builder for an update query. As the above is standard SQL, it should run on any DBMS though. So it won't get much better than that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change user just as soon as the vehicle table is updated by the enduser from the front, then I would suggest when you use Controller assigned to Model Vehicle lets say VehicleController, create an update function. Assuming that you only have one column called Vehicle in Vehicle Table.

```
 //Inside Vehicle Controller
use App\User;       \\call the User model
use App\Vehicle;     \\call the Vehicle model
```

let say the user updates the vehicle with id 202 from form, then in the view create a form and post the id with 202 value in it
eg:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ url('vehicle/'.$id) }}" >
@csrf 
your form inputs and submit button
</form>
```

Then using routes post the form to VehicleController@update (or you can use a resource controller)
eg  `Route::post('vehicle/{id}','VehicleController@update');`
   Then inside Vehicle Controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
        {
               $request->validate([
                  //provide your validation here
             ]);
               $vehicle_req = $request['name_of_input field'];
               //After validation 
                $vehicle = Vehicle::find($id);
                $user = User::find($id);

                $vehicle->update([
                        'Vehicle' => $vehicle_req,
                    ]);
                $user->update([
                        'vehicle_Desc' => $vehicle_req,
                ]);
                return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Value Edited 
                  successfully.');
        }
```

Finally, you can show the success message on the view. It will update both Vehicle Column of Vehicle Table and vehicle_Desc of User table simultaneously.